# Why is pdb.set_trace() not working in a templatetag definition?

Tags: python, django, templatetags

I have written a templatetag to solve the repetitive creation of a special form. Got some problems with the logic, so i inserted pdb.set_trace() to get to its roots. But strangely this set_trace() never seems to be executed when i call the templatetag. The tag looks like this:

```
@register.tag('get_loop_form')
def get_loop_form(parser,token):

    import pdb;pdb.set_trace()

    #put some logic here

    return GetLoopForm()
```

And i simply call it in the template like this:

```
{% get_loop_form %}
```

Usually i get the chance to interact with the script at the line of the set_trace() when i do that. When i insert the set_trace() into the GetLoopForm.render method it works, but not when i insert it into get_loop_form. Why not?

edit: restarted the Django development server manually, which resulted in the code above working. I still do not understand why this happened.

Comment: Did you try restarting the runserver? Since it is a template tag, it might be cached on server start.

Comment: Also, unrelated but you might want to use ipdb instead of pdb. You need to pip install ipdb first.

Comment: Ah, ok. Was the chached templatetag then. Post this as an answer and i'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is a template tag, it might be cached on server start. Try to restart the server, that should solve the problem.